# Labeling "hidden" input fields ( <label></label> )

Tags: jquery, css, html, validation

So i got this jQuery slider plugin that uses hidden dummy input field for it to work. I got 2 of those, and the rest of them are regular inputs. When i try to validate HTML it says

*"The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form 
control."*

Instead of rewriting all the css and rearange loads of nesting, is there an alternative to label tag or what ?

Comment: Does it matter if your HTML validates?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the input in a `<label>` tag? `<label><input type="hidden"/></label>`?!

Comment: @chsdk my guess is they're using the checkbox hack so the css probably uses a sibling selector like `input:checked ~ .someElement { ... }`. If the `input` is in the `label`, the thing you toggle with the `input` is `:checked` would also need to be in a `label`

Comment: Where are you validating this? I just put a hidden input and label in validator.w3.org and it didn't throw an error/warning. Assuming you're using `display: none` have you tried using `visibility` or `opacity` and/or using absolute positioning to move it way off screen some how?

Comment: @chsdk Actually that did it, with a few tweaks it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelCoker at https://html5.validator.nu/ and the slider is http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/

Comment: If a solution was found, please provide and accept an answer. Otherwise, delete the question if it has been abandoned.